# Nested UL - CSS Responsive menu anchor problem

Tags: html, css

I have this simple HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="item">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">Parent</a>
        <ul class="sub-items">
            <li><a href="child-url.html">Child</a></li>
            <li><a href="child-url.html">Child</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">Parent</a>
        <ul class="sub-items">
            <li><a href="child-url.html">Child</a></li>
            <li><a href="child-url.html">Child</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">Parent</a>
        <ul class="sub-items">
            <li><a href="child-url.html">Child</a></li>
            <li><a href="child-url.html">Child</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And this simple CSS

```
<style>
.sub-items {
    display: none;
}

.item:hover .sub-items {
    display: block;
}
</style>
```

This works in desktop, however, in mobile, when you touch on the second or third parent you automatically open the child url. How could I avoid this without using javascript?

Thanks in advance

Comment: post your script as well that you have tried

Comment: why use `<a>` for parent, if you don't want it to be clickable?

Comment: @domenik-reitzner It doesn't solve the problem. And it's a touchable area for mobile version, I guess that it could improve screen reader detection or something... but please, let's focus on the issue.

Comment: did you try it without `<a>`?

Comment: Yes I did, same behaviour

Comment: Can you please explain more in detail. Do you want child elements to be opened onclick of parent one?

Comment: Please note, there is no hover event for mobile devices. So whenever you touch the parent, it will automatically open the URL. You can write a code to open the child links on click, instead of on hover. This will work for both cases i.e in desktop and in mobile also

Comment: _“And it's a touchable area for mobile version, I guess that it could improve screen reader detection or something...”_ - this kind of menu is not screen-reader friendly _at all_. The sub menus are hidden via `display:none`, and a screen reader likely doesn’t apply any `:hover` styles - so those sub menus will most likely be completely unreachable to screen reader users. If you want to implement a screen reader friendly menu, then you should do some research into what the basics of that topic are ...

Comment: I think I wasn't clear... The problem is that whenever I touch the second parent or third parent (after touching the first parent), it opens a child link.

Comment: try adding `pointer-events:none` to `.item > a`

Comment: It is because all the parent has same class name. so when you click on one parent, css is telling them to open all the child where parent is .sub-items

Comment: @AKNair absolutely not true, the selector `.item:hover .sub-items` limits the selection of sub menus to only those that are inside the currently hovered `.item` element.

Answer (score -1):

According to mobile device hover features work as `click or active` events so better approach is `.item:active .sub-items { display: block;}` can we use through media query

```css
.sub-items {
    display: none;
}


@media only screen and (max-width:1240px) {
 .item:hover .sub-items {
    display: block;
}
}

@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
  .item:active .sub-items {
    display: block;
    color:red
    
}
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="item">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">Parent</a>
        <ul class="sub-items">
            <li><a href="child-url.html">Child</a></li>
            <li><a href="child-url.html">Child</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">Parent</a>
        <ul class="sub-items">
            <li><a href="child-url.html">Child</a></li>
            <li><a href="child-url.html">Child</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">Parent</a>
        <ul class="sub-items">
            <li><a href="child-url.html">Child</a></li>
            <li><a href="child-url.html">Child</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I agree, but the problem is still there, it keeps "bubbling", you press the second parent and you'll also click the child link

Comment: Give each parent a different class name and check.

Comment: You can not determine whether a device supports hover based on screen dimensions, that is absolutely the wrong way to go about this.

Comment: I think it has to do with hover action and one can refer few articles on how hover works on touchscreen devices. Please check this link for example: https://www.prowebdesign.ro/how-to-deal-with-hover-on-touch-screen-devices/